# com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json, post

I am trying to parse a JSON in Android, a basic Login and Password Screen
I am getting the following error

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value html body script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted
>   to JSONObject

Here is the PHP CODE

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");

$hostname="sql313.freecluster.eu";
$user="fceu_18433487";
$pass="password";
$dbname="fceu_18433487_testdb";

$db=mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$pass,$dbname);
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$username =$_POST["Email"];
$password = $_POST["Password"];

$statement=mysqli_prepare($db,"SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `Email` = ? AND    `Password` = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$username,$password);

$response = array();$rearray=array();
$response["success"] = false;
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement))
{
$response["success"] = true;
$response["username"] = $username;
$response["password"] = $password;
$rearray["username"] = $username;
$rearray["password"] = $password;

}


echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

And here is My code where I do the Json Parsing in Android

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                        String name12=o.getString("success");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name12,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("lala",error.toString());
            }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Email",e1.getText().toString());
                    params.put("Password",e2.getText().toString());
                    return params;
                }

            };
```

I have tried running this script on Postman but was not able to get any preview
What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: print your json response here

Comment: please attach the short stack trace of exception

Comment: You do not get a json. You get an HTML String

Comment: {
  "success": true,
  "username": "test123@gmail.com",
  "password": "1234"
}

This is my normal expected JSON response

Comment: @Jens , that is what I am wondering . Can you elaborate why am I getting so ?

Comment: @temnoi , I have added the trace of exception in the description

Comment: Call the URL in  a browser and see what is going on. Maybe you get an error page

Comment: If you don't see the response in Postman than something wrong with the request.

Comment: @AyushAggarwal your {"success":true} should be {"success":"true"}

Comment: See this line: JSONObject o = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response)); Can we say, response.getString("username") and similar. No need for conversion

Comment: @Dimitar , I tried that as well , but no use so I thought why not convert it

Comment: @Ayush, can you print what android gets. Something like   Log.d(TAG, response.toString());.

Comment: When I call in browser , I see a "success ":false

Comment: Drv , edited and tried , still not working

Comment: It is not going in the response listener , it is directly going to the error listener. 
That is the whole error

Comment: @AyushAggarwal Can you try reading the response with a different approach. For example, something like this: http://javapapers.com/android/android-json-parsing-tutorial/   There is a utility class here that will get whatever response is. Perhaps you can just parse response and create json out of it.

Comment: @AyushAggarwal are you missing an argument here?  public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
            Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)  ... method, url, NULL?, listener, listener)

Comment: So, you would end up with: new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {...}, new Response.ErrorListener(){...} )